# Zappa is not deploying all the packages in my virtual env to Lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, zappa

I am deploying a django application using Zappa. My application's dependencies are bigger than 1GB in size for this reason I am using `slim_handler:true parameter` in zappa settings as well as increasing ephemeral size of lambda using `"ephemeral_storage": {"Size": 10240},` but still i am getting `error django not found` in my cloudWatch logs.

All my configurations are attached below:

My `zappa_settings.py` file:

`{ "test-staging": { "ephemeral_storage": {"Size": 10240}, "aws_region": "us-west-1", "django_settings": "lu_development.settings", "profile_name": "default", "project_name": "linkedunion-bac", "runtime": "python3.10", "s3_bucket": "zappa-sultan-test-migration", "slim_handler": true } }`

All the packages installed in my virtual env:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
amqp==2.6.1
anyio==4.0.0
argcomplete==3.2.1
asgiref==3.7.2
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
autobahn==23.6.2
Automat==22.10.0
autopep8==2.0.4
backoff==2.2.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.24.8
botocore==1.27.8
celery==4.4.3
certifi==2023.7.22
cffi==1.15.1
cfn-flip==1.3.0
channels==3.0.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==8.1.7
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==41.0.3
daphne==3.0.2
Deprecated==1.2.14
Django==4.0.10
django-cacheops==7.0.1
django-cors-headers==3.14.0
django-debug-toolbar==4.0.0
django-environ==0.4.5
django-mysql==3.9.0
django-ninja==0.22.2
django-redis==5.3.0
django-simple-history==2.12.0
django-storages==1.10
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.6.0
durationpy==0.6
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
factory-boy==3.3.0
Faker==19.3.1
funcy==1.18
gcloud==0.18.3
geographiclib==2.0
geopy==2.4.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
grpcio==1.60.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h11==0.14.0
hiredis==2.2.3
hjson==3.1.0
httpcore==0.17.3
httplib2==0.22.0
httpx==0.24.1
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==6.11.0
incremental==22.10.0
jmespath==0.10.0
JSON-log-formatter==0.5.2
jws==0.1.3
kappa==0.6.0
kombu==4.6.11
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
mdurl==0.1.2
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
mysqlclient==2.0.1
numpy==1.25.2
oauth2client==4.1.2
onesignal-sdk==2.0.0
opentelemetry-api==1.19.0
opentelemetry-distro==0.40b0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.19.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.19.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.19.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http==1.19.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-celery==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-dbapi==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-django==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-logging==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-psycopg2==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-redis==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-requests==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-urllib3==0.40b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-wsgi==0.40b0
opentelemetry-proto==1.19.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.19.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.40b0
opentelemetry-util-http==0.40b0
pandas==2.0.3
pdf2image==1.16.3
pep8==1.7.1
Pillow==10.0.1
placebo==0.9.0
protobuf==3.20.3
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycodestyle==2.11.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.10.1
pydantic==1.9.1
Pygments==2.17.2
PyJWT==2.8.0
pymssql==2.2.5
pyOpenSSL==23.2.0
pyparsing==3.1.1
pypng==0.20220715.0
Pyrebase4==4.4.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-jwt==2.0.1
python-magic==0.4.27
python-memcached==1.59
python-slugify==8.0.1
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0.1
qrcode==7.4.2
querystring-parser==1.2.4
redis==4.6.0
requests==2.25.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rich==13.5.3
rsa==4.9
s3transfer==0.6.2
sentry-sdk==1.9.8
service-identity==23.1.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
text-unidecode==1.3
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
tqdm==4.66.1
troposphere==4.5.3
twilio==7.15.3
Twisted==23.8.0
txaio==23.1.1
typing_extensions==4.7.1
tzdata==2023.3
tzlocal==5.0.1
urllib3==1.26.16
vine==1.3.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
wrapt==1.16.0
zappa==0.58.0
zipp==3.17.0
zope.interface==6.0
```

CloudWatch error I am getting after deployment to lambda via Zappa.

`[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 657, in lambda_handler     return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 241, in lambda_handler     handler = global_handler or cls()   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 150, in __init__     wsgi_app_function = get_django_wsgi(self.settings.DJANGO_SETTINGS)   File "/var/task/zappa/ext/django_zappa.py", line 9, in get_django_wsgi     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Using include parameter,

```
"include": ["path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages"]
```